# MVC Client Side Email Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

java Script Validation in mVC.

I want to apply email validation by Data-anotation on lost Focus.
How to Prevent ASP.NET MVC 3 validation on blur or on Key Up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can Change default Setting of vallidation Using this Code

```
   $(function () {
    var settngs = $.data($('#LoginForm')[0], 'validator').settings;
    settngs.onkeyup = false;
});
```